# Sub-heading widths are not set as desired in HTML Table with table-layout:fixed

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm new to web designing. I wanted to make a Table of fixed width with subheadings. I coded something like this:

```css
 table.all_border *{
                border: 1px solid black;
            }
```

```html
<!-- TABLE 1 -->
<table class="all_border" style="width: 564px; margin-top: 10px; font-size: 0.8em; table-layout:fixed; overflow:hidden;">
    <tr align="center">
        <th style="padding:2.5px; width: 46px;" rowspan="2">Item No</th>
        <th style="padding:2.5px; width: 288px;" rowspan="2">DESCRIPTION</th>
        <th style="padding:2.5px; width: 30px" rowspan="2">Qty</th>
        <th style="padding:2.5px; width: 100px" colspan="2">Rate per Item</th>
        <th style="padding:2.5px; width: 100px" colspan="2">AMOUNT</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th style="width:80px">Rs.</th>
        <th style="width:20px">P.</th>
        <th style="width:80px">Rs.</th>
        <th style="width:20px">P.</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Test Material Test Material Test Material Test Material Test Material Test Material Test Material Test Material Test Material Test Material Test Material Test Material Test Material Test Material Test Material Test Material Test Material </td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>12345678</td>
        <td>00</td>
        <td>12345678</td>
        <td>00</td>
    </tr>
</table>


<!-- TABLE 2 -->
<table class="all_border" style="width: 564px; margin-top: 10px; font-size: 0.8em;">
                <tr align="center">
                    <th style="padding:2.5px; width: 46px;" rowspan="2">Item No</th>
                    <th style="padding:2.5px; width: 288px;" rowspan="2">DESCRIPTION</th>
                    <th style="padding:2.5px; width: 30px" rowspan="2">Qty</th>
                    <th style="padding:2.5px; width: 100px" colspan="2">Rate per Item</th>
                    <th style="padding:2.5px; width: 100px" colspan="2">AMOUNT</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th style="width:80px">Rs.</th>
                    <th style="width:20px">P.</th>
                    <th style="width:80px">Rs.</th>
                    <th style="width:20px">P.</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Test Material</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                    <td>12</td>
                    <td>00</td>
                    <td>12</td>
                    <td>00</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

Now my problem is, the width of the sub-headings in `Table 1` with `table-layout:fixed;` (Rs. and P.) are not set as desired and are divided equally.

However, `Table 2` is having the desired ratio of (Rs. and P.) but the width is not fixed.

How can I get the best out of the two? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any reason you must use `table-layout:fixed;`? why not remove `table-layout:fixed;` and use `width:100%` instead?

Comment: See update, the sub-headers are at 80px/20px now.

Comment: @zer00ne, can you please UNDELETE the answer? I was on an assignment, so I could not see it. Can you please help again?

Comment: Undeleted, sorry about that, I thought it was too much of a specialized answer that it wouldn't be of use to anyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update

The OP requests that the last 4 `<th>`are at 80/20 instead of 50/50. The reason why it doesn't change to 80/20 is because the fixed widths must be applied to the first row in order for the widths to conform to explicit lengths.

1. Removed the `colspan:2` property/values
2. Added 2 `<th>` to the top row of `<thead>`
3. Set the right borders of the `<th>` at 80px width to `0 none rgba(0,0,0,0)`
4. Set the left borders of the `<th>` at 20px width to `0 none rgba(0,0,0,0)`
5. In order to center the text over the 2 `<th>`:

   - Wrap the text in `<b>`
   - Set `position:relative` and `z-index:1`

### Use `<tbody>`

1. Merge both tables because:

   - They represent the same type of data
   - And they are close proximity of each other
2. To merge, remove the end tag `</table>` of the first table
3. Remove the opening tag `<table>` of the second table
4. Insert the following between the 2 tables:

   ```
   <tbody>
    ------Table 1 
   </tbody>

   <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td colspan='7'>
         <div class='space'>&nbsp;</div>
       </td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>

   <tbody>
    ------Table 2
   </tbody>
   ```
5. Wrap the top and bottom table sections in `<tbody>` tags.
6. Once the CSS from the demo below is applied, this table will appear as empty space.

Using multiple `<tbody>` in a table is completely valid, compliant to standards, and actually encouraged. AFAIK, the invisible table is ok but if you're concerned with standards, you can place arbitrary data there (doesn't have to be visible text - `color:transparent`.)

### Demo

```css
table.border td,
table.border th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

tbody:last-of-type>tr:first-child>th {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

tbody:nth-of-type(2) td {
  border: 0 none transparent;
}

.space {
  height: 10px;
  border: 0 none transparent;
}

.c80.c80 {
  width: 80px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: visible;
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: -5px;
  border-right: 0 none rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
}

.c20.c20 {
  width: 20px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: visible;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-left: 0 none rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
}

th b {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #fff;
  margin-left: 8px;
}

td:nth-of-type(odd) {
  text-align: center;
}

td:nth-of-type(even) {
  text-align: right
}

td:nth-of-type(2) {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <table class="border" style="width: 564px; margin-top: 10px; font-size: 0.8em; table-layout:fixed; overflow:hidden;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="padding:2.5px; width: 46px;" rowspan="2">Item No</th>
        <th style="padding:2.5px; width: 288px;" rowspan="2">DESCRIPTION</th>
        <th style="padding:2.5px; width: 30px" rowspan="2">Qty</th>

        <th class='c80'><b>Rate per Item</b></th>
        <th class='c20'></th>
        <th class='c80'><b>AMOUNT</b></th>
        <th class='c20'></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th style="width:80px">Rs.</th>
        <th style="width:20px">P.</th>
        <th style="width:80px">Rs.</th>
        <th style="width:20px">P.</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Test Material Test Material Test Material Test Material Test Material Test Material Test Material Test Material Test Material Test Material Test Material Test Material Test Material Test Material Test Material Test Material Test Material </td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>12345678</td>
        <td>00</td>
        <td>12345678</td>
        <td>00</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td colspan='7'>
          <div class='space'>&nbsp;</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th style="padding:2.5px; width: 46px;" rowspan="2">Item No</th>
        <th style="padding:2.5px; width: 288px;" rowspan="2">DESCRIPTION</th>
        <th style="padding:2.5px; width: 30px" rowspan="2">Qty</th>
        <th style="padding:2.5px; width: 100px" colspan="2">Rate per Item</th>
        <th style="padding:2.5px; width: 100px" colspan="2">AMOUNT</th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <th style="width:80px">Rs.</th>
        <th style="width:20px">P.</th>
        <th style="width:80px">Rs.</th>
        <th style="width:20px">P.</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Test Material</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>00</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>00</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</main>
```

Comment: But.. my problem is not solved. (Rs and P) are spread 50%, not 80 and 20%.

Comment: See update of the aforementioned cells are know at 80/20.

Comment: Thank you very much, and I'm glad you have found it useful, happy coding.